# Extract a polyline from a Geoserver shapefile

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, snapping, bing-maps

I have a GeoServer which contains a shapefile with some roads on it. Is it possible to programmatically query the GeoServer and extract a specific road from it and display it in a layer? I'm using OpenLayers library locally.

The reason I want to do this is because I want my line to be snapped on to the actual roads on my basemap (Bing maps).

Comment: Use CQL queries as in http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply parse your shp file into geoJSON and parse it to a vectorlayer
Look here: https://github.com/wavded/js-shapefile-to-geojson